# Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 when running on device, not simulator

Tags: ios

There's a bucketload of previous questions/answers about this already.

> "Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard
>   iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using
>   563160167_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default"

However all the answers involve changing a setting on the simulator, but I'm not using the simulator, I'm getting this message in the console when running on a phone.

There's also a few more answers when the issue arose trying to change the return key on the keyboard, but I'm not doing that either.

All I have is two UITextFields, one sets the keyboard entry type to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad and the other uses the default keyboard type. That's it.
Then the message appears in the console when the text field set to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad` becomes the first responder.

If I change it to `UIKeyboardTypePhonePad`, then the message becomes

```
 Can't find keyplane that supports type 5 for keyboard.
```

A numeric keypad will appear in both instances *however* it takes a very long time to do so, quite a few seconds. 
If instead of specifying a numeric keypad the UITextField just uses the default keypad then it dose not have this long delay time before it appears.

[XCode 7.3, iPhone 6, iOS 9.2.1]